# Numbers App not fuctioning right

Tags: ios

The Numbers App is not functioning correctly on my iPad Air 2, 
can someone help me ? It's doubling all my spreadsheets, and not allowing me to delete the addional spreadsheets

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes cloud sync can get behind. I would log in to Numbers / iCloud online and determine if you have duplicates and clean them out from the web interface on a computer browser.

- https://www.icloud.com/#numbers

At that point, you can wait for Numbers / iCloud to clear on iOS or go in using iCloud Drive app and clean out the duplicates. You may have to do this on iOS if you don't have easy access to a Mac or computer browser.